# Unexpected token : error when making Ajax json get request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a cross domain ajax request to deezer, a music streaming api... and I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error. I know it's because the data I'm getting back is not in proper json format, but I tried changing the datatype to 'json' from 'jsonp' and it's still not working...here's my request, any suggestions?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.deezer.com/search?q=" + searchString + "&callback=?",
  dataType: 'json',
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used unencoded second "?" in your url after first "?", which using for separate get-string. You need to remove this part of url `+ "&callback=?"`.

Comment: if I remove + "&callback=?", i get the following error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.deezer.com/search?q=travis. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ...which is annoying, because if i click on the link above... it takes me right to the json object i need

Comment: I mean you can't get this request to API this way (with XMLHttpRequest) because "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". I think, you need use this [manual](https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript). Don't forget to create application [here](https://developers.deezer.com/myapps).

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, on Deezer's developer API explorer, you didn't have to specify what format to receive the data, but apparently I needed to specify I wanted JSON in the request to deezer. That fixed the issue